# Wordpress Offline Documentation for Theme development

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just started with wordpress and want to start developing my own themes. I dont have reliable access to the internet so I want to make the wordpress documentation offline. What is the easiest way to do this? I cant seem to find any downloadable documentation. Is there a quick and easy way to make large parts of a website available offline?
Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the site doesn't offer such documentation to download in an archive (they often do), you can always use a "spider" tool (walking the web of page links from the page you target and downloading each related page, a bit like a search engine does) to download a (part of a) site.

For example I think wget is able to do that, or with GUI [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) is a good tool, with lot of parameters.

Warning: you have to carefully set the parameters to avoid, for example, to download a whole site (or even the whole Internet!) when all you want is a documentation.
Some sites also set guards against such spiders because they have limited bandwidth or monthly volume of served data, etc. You can set options to slow down downloading, resume a download, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Wordpress offline Codex documentation February 12, 2012

Link: http://www.filesin.com/48B6F308122/download.html

Comment: Please give me new link. the link was expired.

Comment: Please update the link. The current link seems to go to a malicious domain instead. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try Dash if you are using MacOSX. It allowes you do download the documentation and also search it offline. I like it a lot.

Comment: Just downloaded looks very promising!